# Custom taxonomies template

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have added a new custom post type "Movies" to my wordpress site, and added 3 taxonomies to that post type "Genres & Year & Author".

Now, i want to make a custom template which wordpress will use if someone access the page of any of these three taxonomies:
eg. if some one accessed the taxonomies pages:
"www.sitename.com/genres", "www.sitename.com/year", "www.sitename.com/author".

how can i make a custom template for all taxonomies under "Movies" post type?

Comment: archive-movies.php will show all posts of these taxonomies. For each taxonomy you can use taxonomy-genre.php , taxonomy-author.php , taxonomy-year.php

Answer (score 0):

create specific [taxonomies template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) for  Genres & Year & Author like this :

```
taxonomy-genres.php
taxonomy-year.php
taxonomy-author.php
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, but i was wandering if it's possible to use one template that display posts depending on the requested taxonomy of a custom post type.
eg. Archive.php is responsible for displaying posts of the selected category of all post type, as i have 5 custom post types and if i created a file for each taxonomy the result will be huge number of files!

Answer (score 0):

Create templates by category ID OR Category Slug like (Category name: mobile)
taxonomy-mobile.php

taxonomy-id.php

category-mobile.php

category-id.php

Answer (score 0):

You cannot differentiate the templates for taxonomies according to the post types. You can do that for taxonomy terms.
Your best options will be to create separate templates as suggested by Balwant or use a conditional loop for these three taxonomies in your default taxonomy page.

```
if(is_tax( array('genres', 'year', 'author') ) {
  //your custom template path here
}
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks